# How to expand code in console in sbt shell in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I work with Scala in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3. If I run the console in the sbt shell it works fine, but the code is collapsed and cannot be seen. The output in the window is:

```
[IJ]console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.13.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
>....

(busy) >
```

If I type, say, 2 + 2 I get

```
[IJ]console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.13.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
>....val res0: Int = 4
>....
(busy) >
```

Thus, it works but the code seems collapsed in the ellipsis. This is particular challenging with multi-line statements. Can it be expanded?

Comment: You need to wait until it loading finishes. You will have `console>` when it finishes loading.

Comment: I personally avoid using IntelliJ sbt shell for anything but running tasks. It parses the output and this sometimes results in incorrect results and weird behavior. Especially when you start using autocompletes and reloads it easily "gets lost". For anything more complex (e.g. sbt console which manages IO streams) I would suggest using terminal emulator with sbt shell running in it.